# When using Camera TextureView , occur nullpointerExceptipn on android

Tags: android, textureview

My app camera preview using `TextureView`.

now situation, 
when In my app clicked `button` start wifiapp

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("kr.co.aaa.wifiapp");
startActivity(intent);
```

At this time, call `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` , `onPause`

```
@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}
```

and In wifiapp, click back `button`, restart my app.

at this time, call `onSurfaceTextureAvailable`

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
  try {  
       mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);  //NPE
       mCamera.startPreview();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

When restart my app, occur NullPointerException

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewTexture(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture)'
>   on a null object reference
>         at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.video.CameraTextureView.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(CameraTextureView.java:82)
>         at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:368)
>         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15157)
>         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16187)
>         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15180)
>         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15175)
>         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16187)
>         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15180)
>         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15175)
>         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15175)
>         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16187)
>         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
>         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15180)
>         at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:282)
>         at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:288)
>         at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:323)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2609)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2428)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2061)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6007)
>         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5415)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)

I think occur NPE `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` `mCamera = null;` .

because when my app restart, mCamera status is null call `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` , `mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture)` is null.

so I try delete `mCamera = null`

but occur diffrent error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera is being used after
>   Camera.release() was called
>       at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewTexture(Native Method)
>       at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.video.CameraTextureView.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(CameraTextureView.java:82)
>       at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:368)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15157)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16187)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15180)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15175)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16187)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15180)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15175)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15175)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16187)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15180)
>       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:282)
>       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:288)
>       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:323)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2609)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2428)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2061)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6007)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5415)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)

this error `mCamera.setPrevieTexture(surfaceTexture)`

How to solve this problem?

thanks.

full source

```
public class CameraTexture extends TextureView implement TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
  private Camera mCamera;
  private TextureView mTextureView;

  public CameraTexture(Context context, LiveCamera liveCamera) {
    super(context);

    mCamera = liveCamera.camera;

    mTextureVeiw = (TextureView) activity.findViewById(R.id.live);
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
 }

 @Override 
 public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {

   try {
      mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
      mCamera.startPreview();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } 
 }

 @Override 
 public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
       mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
       mCamera.release();
       mCamera = null; // if delete this line, occur Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called  error
 }

 @Override
 public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    Bitmap bitmap = mTextureView.getBitmap();

    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getWidth()];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
 }
 }


public class LiveCamera {
   public Camera camera;
}
```

if need more information. please comment.
thanks.!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MCEmperor , I know why occur nullpointerException, but I don't know this problem..

Comment: `public CameraTextureView(Context context, LiveCamera liveCamera)` is this constructor??

Comment: @UpendraShah  yes, this is constructor.   update LiveCamera source. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check you class name and constructor name

```
public class CameraTexture extends TextureView implement TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
  private Camera mCamera;
  private TextureView mTextureView;

  public CameraTexture(Context context, LiveCamera liveCamera) {
    super(context);

    mCamera = liveCamera.camera;

    mTextureVeiw = (TextureView) activity.findViewById(R.id.live);
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
 }

//your remain code

}
```

Comment: sorry, constructor name is typo sorry

Answer (score 0):

Save the surfacetexture object to a global variable and If it is null just try to get the saved object from the global variable..